# DataGridView Master-Detail for DTOs?

Tags: .net, datagridview, dto, data-transfer-objects

In my Windows Forms app, I two DataGridViews that represent a Master-Detail relationship.  The datasource for each is a Data Transfer Object, represented as an IList(of T) -- so DataRelation is out.  What is the best way to drive the master-detail grids?  Is there a built-in way to do this in .NET or do I have to write my own rebind when the selected master row changes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding class with master/detail into two datagridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860262/binding-class-with-master-detail-into-two-datagridview)

Answer (score 0):

Process the rowenter event on the master grid.
Populate the details grid manually or update the datasource and rebind.